# Problems with java excel extractor

Tags: java, excel, csv

I wrote some code to extract data from xls and save them into csv. Everything is working great except when I have a time value, it is changing it to a date. How can I avoid that?
For example, if in the xls file it is 119:22:00, it is getting saved to the csv file as 1/4/1900 23:23 with format type as date. How can I keep it the way it is with format as String?

Here is the code:

```
if (sheet != null)
{
    for (currentRow = 0; currentRow < sheet.getRows(); currentRow++)
    {
        row = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cell[] rowCells = sheet.getRow(currentRow);
        for (Cell cell : rowCells)
        {
            System.out.println(cell.getContents());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show us your code for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the Excel.Cell.Text rather than the  Excel.Cell.Value to see the formatted value. Clearly what you're extracting is the value. Based on your code, it looks like the problem will be in `cell.getContents()` or `sheet.getRow()` - whichever is used to extract the data from excel. You should post the content of those functions too.

The underlying values for dates and times in Excel are very hard to deal with, and meaningless to the novice user in their raw format. You can see the underlying value Excel translates your dates and times to just by opening up your excel sheet and temporarily changing the format to `number`. You'll see that as soon as you type in a date or time, it's translating it to a numeric representation of that date or time that will be meaningless to the user, and thus meaningless to you if you extract the underlying value rather than the formatted text.

[image]

Comment: I tried both jxl and apache's poi and in both cases I wasn't able to extract the string value when the cell has type number or date. I am getting cast exceptions. Do you know how to always string value even if the cells contains numbers/dates/etc ?

Comment: I can't help you until you post your code. Also tell me what API you're using. I guarantee you there isn't an Excel API in the world that won't give you some way at getting the Cell Text rather than the Cell Value. It looks like what you're trying to do is call "ToString()" on the cell, which isn't what you should be doing.